# Folding a cube (animation)

Tags: animation, bones

I'm trying to fold a cube with an animation. I've tried inverse kinetics with no luck. Here are some images that explain what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to make this so that

- when the upper bone is pushed down, the box is folded to the ground.
- when the upper bone is pulled up, it unfolds the box.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: "when pushed bottom or top the box is folded to the ground or if up makes the box." could you further explain that?

Comment: The bone in the top of the box, is the main bone. When i push the bone down, its suposed to make the other bones "fold" in order to be like the first example in the second image. If u pull the bone up in the z axis, its suposed to make a box

Comment: ah, thankyou. a bit hard to interpret there... :-D

Comment: No problema, u know how to fix that:s?

Comment: I think you'll have to use **drivers** on the box's bones, to drive them according to the main (top) bone's local position.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

one possible way is to use :

- use the Transformation constraint to convert translation to rotation from control bone to lower bones
- use the copy rotation constraint to make the upper bone rotate in reverse to the lower bone

[image]

- The ***Transformation*** constraint to the lower bone with this settings :

[image]

- the ***Copy rotation*** constraint on the upper bone :

[image]

- there's only one plane ( with middle edge) and have an array modifier controlled by an empty ( see the .blend file )

[image]

Comment: Could u make some explanations how to reach that point? im have almost zero experience in bone managment

Comment: Im having some problems reproducing the same animation...

Comment: @Chebhou, care to elaborate? you have the right answer, but it's unclear to newbies.

Comment: Sorry i was in a hurry , I'll add details now

Comment: @Warianos added the example file you can download

Comment: @Warianos , see the Z-->Y this what's missing for you, on the other two bones put   Z--->X

Comment: Ok now i almost got it, the problem now is that when at the x axis the bone  when inverted automatically inverts 180º and stays on top of the lower bone plane, like the image shows.

Comment: @Chebhou Could u help me with this bug? :) evertything else is already well done

Answer (score 2):

The way Chebhou showed is rather simple:
for each of the 8 bones conected to the box, ad a transform-constraint(constraint-tab in the properties-panel)
use location of the middlebone as input and the rotation on x or y as output

or try this:
parent 4 bones to the top one, each placed at the top of a wall.
for each wall: place the mid a bit outside of the box and add an ik-constraint to the upper bone;
with chainlength=2 and tail=True, the targetbone being the bone placed on top of each wall.

the green one on the top is what you move, the big ones are to deform the walls, the small gray ones are the targets. they are children of the green one on the top. the green one has a limit-location-constraint(seen on the right), the yellow ones each have an ik-konstraint to the little gray ones, with a chainlength of 2
[image: IK-rig]

Comment: Im trying that but when i keep the offset of the 4upper bones to the top one. The bones get disconnected from the bottom ones.

Comment: Try to see the image i psoted there now

Comment: Since i dont understand how to work with constraints its really dificult, im trying but im not getting what i want

Comment: added a picture with my setup