# Suggestions to make a "uwrap" animation with this ball model

Tags: animation

I would like to convert my ball model into a 2d-ish model with an animation. Already tried to find some tutorials or materials presenting ways to do that, without success.

[image: Ball model]

I would like to animate the ball into something like this:

[image: Target representation]

I believe this is a hard thing to do, specially cause I don't have too much experience with Blender (started to model with 3Ds max) or animation, but I would like to try even so. Any ideas or tutorials?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31621/folding-a-cube-animation https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6767/how-to-make-folding-origami-animation/6773#6773 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57976/how-to-simulate-miura-fold

Comment: @vklidu thank you sir, I'll check it out the script, hopefully I'll be able to achieve what I want.

Comment: @vklidu Got this error when tried to activate the convert to armature addon in the Blender 2.79b:

https://imgur.com/a/bPXekvl

Not sure why it's happening, already look in the tool's page but didn't find anyone with this particular error...

Comment: @vklidu reopened, feel free to add your answer.

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking for result like in your second image - ready to use file (print-cut-glue), use build in "**Paper Model Export**" addon by Emu.

But for unfolding, use his "**Convert to Armature**" addon - [download version for 2.8x](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/addam/Export-Paper-Model-from-Blender/master/object_convert_to_armature.py). More info [here](http://addam.github.io/Export-Paper-Model-from-Blender/).

---

### Unfold Animation

- download-install-enable addon
- select object, go to edit mode (Tab), select edges you want split
- Ctr+E > **Mark Seam**
- search **Split Seams**
- additionally select one face you prefer to start generate bone tree
- search **Convert to Armature**

That's all ... to be precise, object is not animated yet. Script generates Armature object with bones assigned to faces and creates unfolded **Pose**. To animate unfolding - go to Pose Mode (Ctrl+Tab), select all bones, add Keyframe (I) > Rotation, move on Timeline, Clear Rotation (Alt+R), add second Keyframe > Rotation.

[image]

If you have more complex mesh you can let "Export Paper Model" script to Mark Seams for you (3Dview > Properties Panel (N) > Paper > Unfold). Continue as described above - search Split Seams ...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I did not test it but I think it's worth a try.

Try TexTools addon. It makes an animation using the UV Mesh and the mesh using Shape keys.

The link: http://renderhjs.net/textools/blender/

[image] 
[image]

Comment: Thanks @LeoNas, I would like to keep the 3D aspect of the ball parts after the animation. But this seems useful indeed, I'll check it out and use it as a prototype at least, if the result is good, I'll stick to it.