# How to model a burger package with beveled edges?

Tags: modeling

I am trying to model a burger box. I used a plane and extrude it for each side. After this was done, I fold the edges to fold the box. As you can see in the image below, it doesn't came perfect out of the box. I think the problem is that the angles of the beveled edges are not the same.

I start all over again, but thought maybe there are some good tips how to achieve a correct burger box. Especially for the angled corners as they should be aligned correctly to each side.

[image: Start over again with a simple plane. But have some questions for the right workflow to get the sides correctly.]

[image: My first try, but as you can see it's not perfectly, as some sides overlaps each other]

Answer (score 6):

In reality, the paper bends to hold the box closed.
In 3D no bending occurs, the paper clips through instead.

[image]

Some pointers for modeling:

1. Model only one half and use *Mirror Modifier* to generate the other
2. Use *Solidify Modifier* to add thickness
3. Make use of Pivot points when rotating (Active element works well)
4. Use [Custom orientations](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/orientation.html#custom-orientations) to rotate angled parts

Using *Pivot Point > Active Element* to rotate around selected vertex.

[image]

Using a *Custom orientation* to rotate an angled flap.

[image]

Comment: I don't want to split your full answer here :) So just a suggestion to use armature in like one click https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/161399/2214 Bones are automatically generated along face and already limited in rotation, so easy to animate (some test from 2011 https://imgur.com/ShLOtUm )

Comment: I'd say that actually deserves a separate answer :). I didn't mention armatures, because I have no experience in that area :). But it seems more convenient.

Comment: You already covered key points. Addon is just an extension in this Q to anim - you just select a face of object and run addon that creates a whole rig, there is not much to say and you dont need experience here I would say. If you would be interested to explore it fill free to extend your A.