# Easiest way to model a candy wrapper?

Tags: modeling

What would be the easiest way to model this kind of candy wrapper?

[image]

I have this template of the wrapper dimensions I need to model (blue lines are where the wrapper folds around the candy, the yellow bars are where the heat seal goes):

[image]

I've tried bringing the template in as a plane, adding edges where the folds go, and then manually bending the planes to 'wrap' the image.  But the problem with this method is I'm getting hard creases on the folds, and beveling them gets messy.

I've tried using curves to bend the planes but I can't seem to make a curve that works.

One caveat is that I have to model it in a way that doesn't increase the geometry, in other words if the plane bends that's fine, but the bend can't stretch the material, if that makes sense.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Easy roads lead to hell (⁠•⁠‿⁠•⁠) try to search pillow tutorials ... Btw Blue line doesn't seem to be correct like that wrapp stay open on shorter sides around candy.

Comment: Thanks for weighing in @vklidu.  Actually the blue lines are correct as the candy that goes in the wrapper is square-ish, and as mentioned the yellow is where the heat seal goes (meaning the yellow parts overlap and are fused together on the ends, and on the flap that does down the middle in the back).

Comment: Yellow I understood, the blue lines - my bad English, I thought you mean blue represents candy dimension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way is to [download](https://www.turbosquid.com/Search/3D-Models/wrapper) some model :)

---

Here is a way with armature (to avoid stretching).
Created base mesh can be later inflated by sculpt mode.

I used your dimensions, later I noticed I need only dotted area (blue in your screen) ...

[image]

... and cut the plane to keep just a quarter (the rest is done by *Mirror* modifier ... and cut this topology (I don't know what dimension candy is, so I cut it for illustration somehow).

[image]

Split angled edge (marked red) to brake circle dependency for add-on **[Convert to Armature](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/161399/2214)**. This great add-on generates armature for you in a proper way that is essential for *Pose* mode. Before you run operator select middle face so add-on knows where to start a bone tree - a root face).

[image]

To rotate bones was for me try&error, also I don't know at what angle should be cut the two angled edges properly (there is probably some math behind).

[image]

[image]

Here the result with modifiers applied and under *Sculpt* mode one click drag cursor with *Cloth Filter* > **Inflate**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow thank you!  Re: Turbosquid, I didn't want to use a stock model because this is for a product label design for a client and the dimensions have to be exact.  I could technically resize the model, but with the depth down the sides I wasn't sure I would be able to calculate that correctly, and I'm not great at UV unwrapping.  I felt that starting from scratch using the actual template that the design goes onto would be best.  And thank you for your solution and project file, I love it!  Definitely have expanded my understanding of how to model stuff ;)

Comment: Great  if it works for you. Yeah depth (thickness) of the product is unknown here, but you can ask customer, right? It would be easier to get result properly. BTW In my blend the two triangles was made after armature was generated by add-on, so I tried to make them manually. But even I checked numbers if fits, there is some small inaccuracy in this area. That is why add-on is a miracle for me for many years. I was never be able to rig something like this manually and avoid shifting when posing. And add-on do it by one click :) Relatively old, but essential for packing design.